# TKIP Encryption not visible

Tags: security, encryption

When I want to connecto to my AP whih uses
Security type = WPA2 - Personal
Encryption = TKIP
There is no field I can enter TKIP encryption, I am asked only for Name, security type and Security key

---

I cannot connect if I just enter SSID and Security key.

The strange thing is I made a teathering AP from my LG Android phone and Ubuntu connected without problem.... The AP I am using is used by at least 6 devices in my house and every of my friends when come, they connect it with no problem

So, bottom line is - cannot connect AP from Ubuntu, but CAN connect on a phone which plays a role of AP (teathering)

Comment: Can you connect to it? I think it's automatically detected if it's TKIP or other encryption types.

Comment: ...so what happens when you enter the key, and click Connect?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, I boot into Ubuntu and I am unable to connect to wifi, in windows I just changed the encryption type to be TKIP and the problem was solved.How to do same in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the security setting in the mean time just to troubleshoot things out, please do so and connect to your network without it. If you can connect, then it most likely, your Ubuntu is having problems with handling encryptions. Read more below:

It has been a known issue that Ubuntu 12.04 is having some problem handling TKIP encrytion. So I suggest that you change your router security encryption setting to WPA/AES (or anything except TKIP).

This is based on experience, by the way. I have a laptop dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. In Windows I have no problem with connecting to any WiFi hot spots, in Ubuntu too but I realized that there's one specific WiFi hotspot that I cannot connect to because the encryption type is TKIP. I suggested to change the encryption type to anything except this one and everything worked out fine.

This also has been discussed loooong ago. Please see the following questions for reference:

https://superuser.com/questions/642867/wireless-internet-connection-does-not-work-wired-connection-has-internet/642907

[Wifi Connectivity problems when using WPA/WPA2 Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131436/wifi-connectivity-problems-when-using-wpa-wpa2-encryption)

And also this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/481432

The solutions on the bug report should help you get through your problem.

Good luck!