# How to fix wifi problem with wpa & wpa2 personal security in kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, network-manager

I've been searching all over the internet for a solution. I have installed Kubuntu 16.04 and my wifi adapter ir a RTL8188CE. My problem is that I can't configure an access point with WPA & WPA2 Personal security, it connects fine, but when I'm going to connect my android phone gives me an Incorrect Password error each time I've tried. Then I changed the security type to WEP 40/128 bits and all works well.

I first tried to fix it by installing a different driver than the one from the repository as described here in one of the comments: 
[Wifi Connectivity problems when using WPA/WPA2 Encryption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131436/wifi-connectivity-problems-when-using-wpa-wpa2-encryption)

And I used this instead:
https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/

But didn't work, the wifi keeps doing the same thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Avoid any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and TKIP.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much of wifi security standards. May I ask why?

Comment: Because some Linux drivers for some WiFi chipsets don't like it. And the experts recommendation is WPA2-AES only anyway, for any device / any OS.